# SQL Multiply a field if another field in same group contains a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a small data set

```
SELECT PID, PCODE, PVAL
FROM mytable
```

Outputs:

```
PID PCODE PVAL
2   N50   £1,000.00
2   B10   £100.00
2   P40   £500.00
3   B10   £100.00
3   P40   £500.00
4   B10   £100.00
4   P40   £500.00
```

I want to output the same fields except if a PID group has a PCODE of N50 in it, then their B10 needs to be reduced by 5% of the N50 like so.

Expected Output:

```
PID PCODE PVAL
2   N50   £1,000.00
2   B10   £50.00
2   P40   £500.00
3   B10   £100.00
3   P40   £500.00
4   B10   £100.00
4   P40   £500.00
```

I have tried using a subquery for this and a case statement but cant get the values to match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression and `max` function to do this. This assumes a pid can only have one row with pcode=N50.

```
select pid,pcode
,case when pcode='B10' then pval-0.05*max(case when pcode='N50' then pval else 0 end) over(partition by pid)
 else pval end as pval
from mytable t
```

Edit: One way to restrict the result to years that contain B10 code is

```
select pid,pcode
,case when pcode='B10' then pval-0.05*max(case when pcode='N50' then pval else 0 end) over(partition by pid)
 else pval end as pval
from mytable t
where yearcolumn in (select yearcolumn from mytable where pcode='B10')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with analytic functions:

```
SELECT PID, PCODE,
       (PVAL -
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN PCODE = 'N50' THEN PVAL * 0.05 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PID), 0)
       ) as PVAL
FROM mytable;
```

Actually, the `COALESCE()` is not necessary:

```
SELECT PID, PCODE,
       (PVAL -
        SUM(CASE WHEN PCODE = 'N50' THEN PVAL * 0.05 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PID)
       ) as PVAL
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Neither of these do anything to the B10 field

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a left join to get a match only when the main table has 'B10' and the second table has 'N50'.
If there is a match: return PVAL discounted by 5% of the N50 PVAL.
If there is not match : return PVAL

```
SELECT t1.PID, T1.PCODE, t1.PVAL - isnull( .05 * t2.PVAL, 0) PVAL
  FROM mytable t1
    left join #mytable t2 
        on t1.PID = t2.PID and t1.PCode = 'B10' and t2.PCode = 'N50'
```